# How to do multiple filters on click event in Angular.Js?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, filter

I am showing different articles from the JSON file and I want to filter the articles based on "Category", "Locations", "date". So If I select any category then the result should filtered out based on the specific category and then if I select location then result should be filtered out based on category and location. Please check my running code here "http://plnkr.co/edit/1vcIAPSwvxQcbIzMhyzp?p=preview"

Please check my code html code:

```
<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
<h2>By Category</h2>
<ul >
  <li ng-repeat="category in categories | filter:{parent: 0}:true | uniqueCategoryFilter">{{category.id}} - {{category.title}} - {{category.parent}}</li>
</ul>
</div> 

<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
<h2>By Location</h2>
<ul >
  <li ng-repeat="location in taxonomy_location | uniqueLocationFilter">{{location.title}}</li>
</ul>
</div> 
   <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
  <h2>By Date</h2>
<ul >
  <li ng-repeat="article in posts">{{article.date}}</li>
</ul>
</div> 

 <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
<ul ng-repeat="article in posts">
  <li><a href="{{article.url}}"><img src="{{article.thumbnail}}" /><h2>{{article.title}}</h2><span >{{article.date | date:'mm/dd/yyyy'}}</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Please check my javascript code here:

```
function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http({
method: 'GET',
url: 'json_price_1.json'
  }).success(function(data) {
$scope.posts = data.posts; // response data
$scope.categories = [];
$scope.taxonomy_location = [];
angular.forEach(data.posts, function(article, index) {

  angular.forEach(article.categories, function(category, index){
    $scope.categories.push(category);


  });
  angular.forEach(article.taxonomy_location, function(location, index){
    $scope.taxonomy_location.push(location);
  });
});
 });
}
```

Comment: I'm only looking at this to help my own understanding of angular so I am not going to attempt an answer. That said, check out this version of your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EeXmvRtCXkZ4HkO26hro?p=preview

Comment: ..and with underscore: http://plnkr.co/edit/gq23G00LKwuLM4xYgiiv?p=preview

Comment: @Malk, Thanks for your help. I am now using your code for filters. I am now separating parent categories in different UL but i want if user selects parent category then child categories should select based on that. so I am using "paren:0" for parent categories. So I want to match parent's category ID with child category's parent ID  Please check me code here http://plnkr.co/edit/RfpYDlKIimeuPH5bzJVx